# Windows API Simulate Keypress from Different Keyboards (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard

Using the Windows C++ API, how can I send input from my program into a window, while saying it came from a specific keyboard? This code works:

```
KEYBDINPUT ki = {
        VK_RIGHT,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0L
};
INPUT input;
input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input.ki = ki;

SendInput(
        1,
        &input,
        sizeof(INPUT)
);
```

but does not let me say which keyboard it's "coming" from.

Comment: `SendInput` doesn't allow you to specify the hardware source. It injects input at a point where no hardware information is available anymore.

Comment: Is there a lower-level API to do that?

Comment: I'm not aware of an API that allows you to inject raw input packets.